# How to achieve Uber Eats horizontal menu animation?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to achieve the same Uber Eats horizontal menu animation, so the categories are scrolled to X position 0 when the respective category is visible on Y axis.

[image]

This is what I have so far

1. First a handleScroll function to retrieve the Y position and onLayout to have the position of each category view.

```js
 <Animated.ScrollView
            ref={scrollView => (this.scrollView = scrollView)}
            scrollEventThrottle={5}
            onScroll={Animated.event(
              [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }],
              {
                useNativeDriver: true,
                listener: event => {
                  this.handleScroll(event);
                }
              }
            )}
          >
          
<FeedContainer key={index} onLayout={this.onLayout(category)}>
```

2. Then the handleScroll function that checks the position minus the header bar in order to retrieve the active category view on Y axis.

```js
  handleScroll = event => {
    const scrollPosition = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const category = this.state.positions.reduce((previous, position) => {
      if (
        position.y - 140 < scrollPosition &&
        position.y + position.height - 140 > scrollPosition
      ) {
        return (previous = position.category);
      }
      return previous;
    }, '');

    const xPosition = this.state.horizontalPositions.reduce(
      (previous, position) => {
        if (category === position.category) {
          return (previous = position.x);
        }
        return previous;
      },
      0
    );
```

3. Last, on my horizontal bar component I pass the y position and perform the scrolling.

```js
onChangeTab = category => {
    const { onChangeTab } = this.props;
    onChangeTab(category);
    const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const maxScroll = this.state.maxPosition.x - width;

    let cordinateFromCategory = this.state.positions.reduce(
      (previous, current) => {
        if (current.category == category) {
          return (previous = current.x);
        }
        return previous;
      },
      0
    );

    if (cordinateFromCategory > maxScroll && Platform.OS == 'ios') {
      cordinateFromCategory = maxScroll;
    }

    this.props.customRef = scrollViewTab => {
      scrollViewTab.getNode().scrollTo({
        x: cordinateFromCategory,
        animated: true
      });
    };
  };
```

Overall it seems that the behaviour is near to the expected one, but as you can see in the gif below, the horizontal bar only scrolls to X position when the Y scroll is completely stopped.

[image]

How could I achieve a smooth effect like Uber Eats one?